# React-Native nested Flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I'm trying to display profile of cooks with the images this person may have. I have an array of cooks with some information like name and profile picture. Cooks array also contains an array of pictures. I would like to display cook.profile Pic name and then the list of photos linked to their profile. I am able to display name and profile Pics but I am not sure how to display array of pictures under each cook's name(horizontal scroll).
**here is the cooks array:**

```
cooks = [{
        "id": "1001",
        "firstName": "Mike",
        "profilePic": "Portrait.jpg",
        "photos": [{
                "url": "img.jpg"
            },
            {
                "url": "img2.jpg"
            },
            {
                "url": "img3.jpg"
            },
            {
                "url": "img4.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1002",
        "firstName": "Marla",
        "profilePic": "profilePic.jpg",
        "photos": [{
                "url": "img1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "url": "img2.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "favorite": "true",
                "url": "img3.jpg"
            },
            {
                "url": "img4.jpeg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

==================================================================

```
    <FlatList
        data={this.props.cooks}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity >
            <CardSection>
              <View style={thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                <Image
                  style={thumbnailStyle}
                  source={{ uri: item.profilePic }}
                />
                </View>
                <View style={headerContentStyle}>
                  <Text style={headerTextStyle}>{item.firstName}</Text>
                </View>
          </CardSection>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {/*
            following part is not working as expected.
          */}
          <FlatList
              data={item.photos}
              renderItem={({ item2 }) =>
              <View>
                <Image
                  style={imageStyle}
                  source={{ uri: item2.url }}
                />
              </View>
            }
            keyExtractor={(item2, index) => index}
          />
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      />
```

===========================================================

```
const styles = {
  iconStyle: {
      paddingLeft: 10,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      height: 23,
      width: 25
  },
  containerStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1
  },
  inputStyle: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    fontSize: 30,
    height: 30,
    width: 350
  },
  headerContentStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    paddingTop: 20
  },
  headerTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 25
  },
  thumbnailStyle: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    height: 100,
    width: 100
  },
  thumbnailContainerStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10
  },
  imageStyle: {
    height: 400,
    flex: 1,
    width: null
  }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean for `not working as expected.`?

+ Not show
+ or Error/Exception

Comment: I shouldn't have said "not working as expected". First of all I am not sure if I can nest a FlatList like this. When i run the above code, I am geting error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined. when check the console log for the ...cooks.photos, i can see the property 'url'. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: please recheck your `cooks` data that you provided above. It is not valid json

Comment: sorry, messed up while cutting short the json. I updated it now.

Comment: I think its not possible unless you have vertical list as parent and horizontal as child or vice versa

Comment: That is what i looking for. I did tried to make the parent vertical and child horizontal. but, no success yet.

Comment: I checked the code & data you provided. It looked good. that error may from somewhere else. Let recheck all usages of `url`

Comment: Thanks for checking. I found a solution while debugging. photos here `data={item.photos}` is an object. I converted object into array using lodash. It is working, but not sure if this is the optimum way to do it.

Comment: @BikramSingh if your `photos` was an object and its key was the `photo's id` and its value was a `photo` then you can get a lightweight array by `Object.keys(photos)`. This returns an array of `id`. Pass this new array to `data` of `FlatList`. So your `renderItem` will has arg as `({ id })`. => you can access any `photo` by `photos[id]`

Answer (score 12):

You can implement SectionList from 'react-native' library instead of using an nested FlatList. Its easier and a better solution. You have all the documentation up [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist). Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that i created in one of my Projects. Take a look it may help you

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: "",
      dummy: [
        {
          _id: "5e12905eb10fe53808d1ca55",
          name: "WHY NAME EXISTS -_-",
          stage: "Confirmed",
          feedback: {
            _id: "5e12905eb10fe53808d1ca56",
            rating: 1,
            review: "bad bad only bad."
          },

          itemDetails: [
            {
              _id: "5e12905eb10fe53808d1ca5a",
              nameXquantity: "Lehsun Adrak x100",
              individualTotal: 155
            },
            {
              _id: "5e12905eb10fe53808d1ca59",
              nameXquantity: "Lehsun x50",
              individualTotal: 25
            },
            {
              _id: "5e12905eb10fe53808d1ca58",
              nameXquantity: "Lehsun Adrak Dhaniya Shimla mirch x Infinity",
              individualTotal: 9969
            }
          ],

          __v: 0
        }
      ]
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.dummy}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                <FlatList
                  data={item.itemDetails}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.nameXquantity}</Text>}
                  keyExtractor={item => item._id}
                />
              </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item._id}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: It is not advisable to use FlatList under scrollview

Comment: It doesn't have a good performance at all, especially on iOS, too much legging